# sigint handler in C

Tags: c, exception, control-flow, sigint

In my main program, I have the following code

```
while(flag == 0)
    ;
```

and I have

```
void sigint_handler(int sig) 
{   
    count = 1;
    return;
}
```

So I am just setting a global flag to 1 when the user presses ctrl+c. However, this does not work for some reason. I then changed my main program to

```
while(flag == 0)
    sleep(1);
```

and this does work. This is rather strange. Could someone help me understand what is going on here and why it did not work initially?

Comment: I think you have an inconsistency there - you're setting ```count``` but checking ```flag```.

Comment: Optimiser may have changed the code to `while(true)`. Try declaring the flag as `volatile`.

Comment: You need to declare the flag `volatle sig_atomic_t`.